# Duplicate annotation Error in appium

Tags: java, appium

I'm working in appium in ubuntu pc. There is a duplicate annotation error in my code

```
   public class ChainViewPageObjects {

    @AndroidFindBy(className = "android.widget.ScrollView")
    @AndroidFindBy(accessibility = "container2")
    @AndroidFindBy(accessibility = "textView")
    @iOSFindBy(accessibility = "container2")
    @iOSFindBy(accessibility = "textView")
    public MobileElement views;

    @HowToUseLocators(androidAutomation = ALL_POSSIBLE, iOSAutomation = ALL_POSSIBLE)
    @AndroidFindBy(className = "fakeID1")
    @AndroidFindBy(accessibility = "fakeID2")
    @AndroidFindBy(accessibility = "container2")
    @iOSFindBy(className = "fakeID1")
    @iOSFindBy(accessibility = "fakeID2")
    @iOSFindBy(accessibility = "container2")
    public MobileElement allPossibleView;

    @HowToUseLocators(androidAutomation = ALL_POSSIBLE, iOSAutomation = ALL_POSSIBLE, iOSXCUITAutomation = ALL_POSSIBLE)
    @AndroidFindBy(className = "fakeID1")
    @AndroidFindBy(accessibility = "fakeID2")
    @AndroidFindBy(accessibility = "container2")
    @iOSFindBy(className = "fakeID1")
    @iOSFindBy(accessibility = "fakeID2")
    @iOSFindBy(uiAutomator = "scrollViews().firstWithPredicate(\"value CONTAINS 'View one' \")")
    @iOSXCUITFindBy(iOSNsPredicate = "label contains 'View one'")
    @iOSXCUITFindBy(className = "fakeID1")
    @iOSXCUITFindBy(accessibility = "fakeID2")
    public MobileElement locatorUsage;

    }
```

Error :

```
Error:(3, 33) java: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class ChainViewPageObjects
  location: package com.wordpress.pageobjects
Error:(16, 12) java: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class ChainViewPageObjects
  location: class com.wordpress.pages.ChainViewPage
Error:(20, 36) java: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class ChainViewPageObjects
  location: class com.wordpress.pages.ChainViewPage
/home/naveen/IdeaProjects/Appium-master/src/test/java/com/wordpress/pageobjects/NotificationPageObjects.java
Error:(18, 5) java: repeated annotations are not supported in -source {0}
  (use -source 8 or higher to enable repeated annotations)
```